# is there a way to prevent network manager from storing the password for a wireless network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, networkmanager

Our corporate wireless network uses continuously changing passwords with RSA tokens.
So every time we need to connect to the wireless we need to enter a new password off the RSA token. For extra fun using the wrong password a couple of times in a row causes the users account to be locked.

Network manager automatically stores and reuses the password, with the net result that it is constant getting my account locked.

Is there some way to prevent it from storing my password for that network?

Or perhaps someway to get the gnome keyring to not store it?

Comment: It may help to know which Linux distribution you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The network manager provides you a checkbox to "Save Password" as far as I remember. Please check it.